# '0xEF' is an invalid escapable character within a JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I got this strange message when parsing a json configuration file:

> "JsonReaderException: '0xEF' is an invalid escapable character within
> a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped. LineNumber: 3 |
> BytePositionInLine: 11."

The content of the json file is:

```
{
  "books": {
    "Content": [
      "運作"
    ]
  }
}
```

There is no such char '0xEF' in the configuration file, and nothing to escape.

The C# code as following:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

// ...

config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "config.json"))
  .Build();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Note**:

1. as I memtioned above, "there is no such char '0xEF' in the configuration file", but the message is showing "'0xEF' is an invalid escapable character within a JSON string". Where does it come from?
2. The configuration file is the right file, all information posted above are double confirmed.
3. The byte representaion of the word 運作 is: byte[] { 0xff 0xfe 0x4b 0x90 0x5c 0x4f }.
4. The issue is created by the word "運", all other words are working fine. Is there certain words are not allowed as string in json file?

Comment: *There is no such char '0xEF'* - Open it in a hex editor and check again? Is the file an e.g. Unicode file that is being read as ascii?

Comment: Saved as UTF-8, `"運作" == byte[]{ 0xe9, 0x81, 0x8b, 0xe4, 0xbd, 0x9c }`. What you want is probably "\u904b\u4f5c".

Comment: Are you sure you look at the correct JSON file? Use Process Monitor to see which config file your build script really accesses.

Comment: answer to Thomas Weller: yes, actually, the issue is created by the word "運". Not sure that the word problem is. All other words works fine.

Comment: Right, so how is that character/word represented in the file, in terms of bytes? I suggest you take a hex dump of the file, and edit your question to tell us *exactly* which bytes are in the file.

Comment: I've put the hex dump in notes above for a while. Any idea?

Comment: No one has the answer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the file at initialization encoding is ANSI. Change encoding json file to UTF-8 BOM.

Answer (score 0):

(**＂**) aka the [Fullwidth Quotation Mark](https://unicode-table.com/en/FF02/) *(FWQM)* is not (**"**) aka the [Quotation Mark](https://unicode-table.com/en/0022/) *(QM)*.

*FWQM* (**＂**) is a character which has for UTF-8 encoding `EF BC 82`. Hence the origin of the `0xEF` byte.

There is probably a *FWQM* (**＂**) instead of a *QM* (**"**) somewhere in the JSon file.